# Can we quote parts of novels in our questions and answers?

Tags: support, citations, copyright

I recently answered this RPG.SE question: [Who is pictured on the cover of Dragonlance Adventures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140411/63061m) I quoted some parts of the novel as support for my answer.

I was wondering if we are allowed to quote text from novels as we do for rules from manuals, or if we have to pay attention to copyright and/or other law aspects.

I suppose that once the reference is clear, there is no problem in quoting parts of such novels, but I would like to clearly understand what are the limits, if any, of this approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it falls solidly into the “fair use” exception to copyright claims.  There is no difference between novels and game books as far as this goes.  Just do not quote excessively; quote enough to support the point only.